# Linux command to find and delete Files which contain a given text

Tags: command-line, command, delete

Is there a terminal command to delete files which contain a given text?

Let's say I have three files and some of them contains the text "extract($_REQUEST)":

- `file-1.php`: This file contains the text "extract($_REQUEST)"
- `file-2.txt`: I don't
- `file-3.html`: This file contains the text "extract($_REQUEST)"

The command I'm looking for will delete the files: `file-1.php` and `file-3.html`.

---

**UPDATE**: The file should delete the file **ONLY IF** "extract($_REQUEST)" is the only line of text in the file. See the examples below:

- `file-4.php`: This file **JUST** contains the text "extract($_REQUEST)"
- `file-5.php`: This file contains the text "extract($_REQUEST)" **and other lines of text**

Then command will delete `file-4.php` and will not delete `file-5.php`.

Comment: can we assume a single <LF> at the end of the file, or is that optional?

Comment: is there such a thing as a line of non text?

Answer (score 6):

```
find  . -maxdepth 1 -type f \
  -exec fgrep -q  'extract($_REQUEST)' '{}' ';' \ 
  -not -exec fgrep -vq  'extract($_REQUEST)' '{}' ';' \ 
  -delete
```

- `find  .` search the current directory
- `-maxdepth 1` and no subdirectories
- `-type f` finding files
- `-exec` and for each execute this test

  - `fgrep` a plain string search

    - `-q`    with no visible output
    - `'extract($_REQUEST)'` for this string
    - `'{}'` in the file you found
    - `';'`  [end of exec]
- `-not` not the next test

  - `-exec` exec again

    - `fgrep` fgrep again

      - `-vq` but this time look for non-matching lines
      - `'extract($_REQUEST)'` same pattern to look for
      - `'{}'` in the file
  - `';'`  [end of exec]
- `-delete` delete them

This works because exec is also a test and when fgrep finds a match the the test succeeds and the delete runs. if grep returns false the delete is not done.

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: no you've changed it completely.

Comment: @Jasen Not really. Just change your `grep` to `! -exec grep -q -v -Fx '...' {} \;`  (you may want to test that first though)

Comment: Ah now I understand use that to check for other lines, in addition to the existing test

Answer (score 4):

```
grep -FRl 'extract($_REQUEST)' | xargs rm -fv
```

- `grep` - search text in files.
- `-F` - treat the string as is, ignore possible regular expressions.
- `-R` - recursive search.
- `-l` - only print filenames.
- `xargs` - give the output to the next program.
- `rm` - remove.
- `-f` - force (don't ask "Are you sure?").
- `-v` - is optional, it will pring the files that were removed.

**UPDATE:**

In order to delete only the files with exact text, I suggest checking the amount of characters in the file as well.

```
for i in $(grep -FRl 'extract($_REQUEST)'); do [[ $(cat $i | wc -c) == "19" ]] && rm -fv $i; done
```

- `wc -c` - counts the characters in the file. Since the example you provided (`extract($_REQUEST)`) is 19 characters long (that includes newline character), I used this number in my example, feel free to change it to fit your situation.

Comment: Fair point, updated the answer @muru

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: @JPashs updated the answer

Comment: maybe he changed it again - too hard to look. but that doesn't check that this is the only line...

Comment: @Jasen I can't think of a scenario that will fail with my command. You grep for a very specific string that is n characters long. And you check if the lengh of the file is n characters. If its not the only line, the check will fail. I believe its sophisticated enough, but if you can give me an example of false positive check, I will be grateful.

Comment: @Jasen unless the OP has not a very specific string (for example it can be either `extract($_REQUEST_1)'` or `extract($_REQUEST_12)'`), then yes, my command will fail in some cases. But he should specify it separately and we will have to update our answers once again. Like use `wc -l` instead of `wc -c`

Comment: I missed that somehow... but still it could be with or without newline at the end.

Comment: `cat` will always add a newline character. If the file already has one, then `cat` will add a second one.

Comment: Will `cat` add a newline? Which `cat`? Here, with the one from GNU coreutils: `printf '%s' foo >file; cat file | od -An -tx1` gives `66 6f 6f`, no newline added.

Comment: My bad. I didn't `printf` my example, only edited it with `vim` and it added the newline upon save.

Answer (score 1):

Command

```
find  . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec grep -l  "string_to_be_searched" {} \;|awk '{print $1}'| sed "s/\.\///g"| awk '{print "rm -rvf" " " $1}'| sh
```

Note: Tested and it worked fine

Comment: should be frgrep because the search sting contains special characters.

Comment: Please let me know the reason for downvote

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: I had no idea how it would work. But I tried it after all simpler suggestions failed... and it worked perfectly! Many thanks.

Comment: (1) This seems like a case where ``-exec … {} +`` would work.  (2a) What’s the point of `awk '{print $1}'`?  (2b) It (`awk '{print $1}'`) breaks filenames that contain whitespace.  (3) Why strip off `./`?  `rm ./file-1.php` works just fine, but `rm $1` breaks if the filename begins with a **`-`**.  (4) Why specify the `-r` option to `rm` when you’re passing it only the names of plain files, never directories?  (5) Why say `"rm -rvf" " "` when you could say simply `"rm -rvf "`? … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (6a) Constructing commands from input beyond your control and piping them into the shell is incredibly dangerous. Imagine what could happen if a filename contained a ``;``.  (6b) Piping commands into the shell will fail for filenames that contain ampersand (`&`), apostrophe, backslash, dollar sign (`$`), parentheses, brackets, vertical bar (**`|`**), and perhaps other special characters.